# How to account for an empty NoteID field in existing records

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen that uses the 'Related Entity' control, and it works correctly.  The only problem now is that in order for it to work properly with my custom screens, a NoteID field with a related [PXNote] attribue has been added to the custom tables.  Unfortunately, for existing records, that NoteID field doesn't have any value - and so the 'Related Entity' control can't add any existing records to the control.  It just ignores the selection.

Since it's a GUID, How do I update existing records to have a valid NoteID GUID?  Can I just run a SQL script that generates a random GUID and updates the records, or is there something special about the GUID generated by the [PXNote] attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just run a SQL script that generates a random GUID and updates
>   the records

Yes probably, use library method to generate GUID to enforce uniqueness.

> or is there something special about the GUID generated by the [PXNote] attribute?

No it's using standard library methods to generate GUID.